# How can I reference my script to use in a Detail.cshtml page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml shared master view, I have this script included

```
<script src="@Url.Script("~/Scripts/PromptToSave.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can this be included in a Details or index page that does not have a layout?

Comment: what you are asking ???????

Comment: You can include it in the same way ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I had to actually create a new function in my script page to reference the pages. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `Details.cshtml` page, if you have

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

and are defining an entire page on its own, simply include the script tag and link anywhere in the page (probably at the top or in the head depending on what the javascript actually looks like)

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<html><head>
<script src="@Url.Script("~/Scripts/PromptToSave.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body>
...rest of page
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add by just copy that script file from your solution then paste it in the markup where the head element resides.

```
 @{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="~/scripts/javascript1.js"></script>
</head>
```